# dynamically create tabcontrol pages, add rich text box, and connect to certain serial port

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a tabcontrol (no tabs by default).  On form load, another form opens asking which switch and how many ports are needed.  Based on how many ports are needed, tab pages are created in the tab control for each port needed.  Once the tab page is created, a richtextbox is added.  in that text box, i need to connect to a specific serial port and output the info into the richtextbox.  the specific serial port changes with the tabpage and is based on what switch was originally selected.  For example, if I pick switch 1, and 3 ports needed, 3 tabs should open and tab 1 should connect to switch1/1(which is actually com35 on my pc), tab 2 should connect to switch1/2(which is com36 on my pc) and so on.  Attached is all my code.

Main Form:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Main

Public Property t_startForm As Object

Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    t_startForm = GetStartForm()

    Dim t_tabList As List(Of Integer) = GetTabs.SetTabs()
    For Each t_tab In t_tabList
        Dim page As New TabPage(String.Format("RCP" & t_startForm.getRCP & " - Port #" & t_tab & ""))
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(page)

        Dim ctrlSiteSpecific As SiteSpecific = New SiteSpecific
        page.Controls.Add(ctrlSiteSpecific)
        ctrlSiteSpecific.Dock = DockStyle.Top

        Dim rtbTab As LoggerBox = New LoggerBox
        page.Controls.Add(rtbTab)
        rtbTab.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
        rtbTab.Name = "rtbRCP" & t_startForm.GetRCP & ""

        'THIS IS WHERE I WANT IT TO CONNECT TO A SERIAL PORT'
    Next
End Sub

Function GetStartForm() As Object
    Dim t_startForm As Start = New Start
    t_startForm.ShowDialog()

    Return t_startForm
End Function

End Class
```

Start Form

```
Public Class Start

Public Function GetRCP() As Integer
    If cbRCP.SelectedItem = Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Return cbRCP.SelectedItem
End Function

Private Sub cbRCP_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbRCP.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim t_rcp As Integer = cbRCP.SelectedItem
End Sub

Public Function GetPorts() As Integer
    If cbPorts.SelectedItem = Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Return cbPorts.SelectedItem
End Function

Private Sub cbPorts_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbPorts.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim t_Ports As Integer = cbPorts.SelectedItem
End Sub

Private Sub Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cancel.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
End Class

Imports System.IO.Ports
```

Get Tabs Class

```
Public Class GetTabs

Public Shared Function SetTabs() As List(Of Integer)
    Dim t_tabs As New List(Of Integer)

    Select Case Main.t_startForm.GetPorts()
        Case 1
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
            End With
        Case 2
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
            End With
        Case 3
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
            End With
        Case 4
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
            End With
        Case 5
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
            End With
        Case 6
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
            End With
        Case 7
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
            End With
        Case 8
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
            End With
        Case 9
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
            End With
        Case 10
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
            End With
        Case 11
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
            End With
        Case 12
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
            End With
        Case 13
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
            End With
        Case 14
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
            End With
        Case 15
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
            End With
        Case 16
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
                .Add(16)
            End With
        Case 17
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
                .Add(16)
                .Add(17)
            End With
        Case 18
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
                .Add(16)
                .Add(17)
                .Add(18)
            End With
        Case 19
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
                .Add(16)
                .Add(17)
                .Add(18)
                .Add(19)
            End With
        Case 20
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
                .Add(16)
                .Add(17)
                .Add(18)
                .Add(19)
                .Add(20)
            End With
        Case 21
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
                .Add(16)
                .Add(17)
                .Add(18)
                .Add(19)
                .Add(20)
                .Add(21)
            End With
        Case 22
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
                .Add(16)
                .Add(17)
                .Add(18)
                .Add(19)
                .Add(20)
                .Add(21)
                .Add(22)
            End With
        Case 23
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
                .Add(16)
                .Add(17)
                .Add(18)
                .Add(19)
                .Add(20)
                .Add(21)
                .Add(22)
                .Add(23)
            End With
        Case 24
            With t_tabs
                .Add(1)
                .Add(2)
                .Add(3)
                .Add(4)
                .Add(5)
                .Add(6)
                .Add(7)
                .Add(8)
                .Add(9)
                .Add(10)
                .Add(11)
                .Add(12)
                .Add(13)
                .Add(14)
                .Add(15)
                .Add(16)
                .Add(17)
                .Add(18)
                .Add(19)
                .Add(20)
                .Add(21)
                .Add(22)
                .Add(23)
                .Add(24)
            End With
    End Select

    Return t_tabs
End Function

End Class
```

And what I'm attempting to use to build my list of serial ports

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class GetPorts

#Region "RCP01"
Public Shared Function GetRCP1Ports() As List(Of IO.Ports.SerialPort)
    Dim t_RCP1 As New List(Of IO.Ports.SerialPort)

    With t_RCP1
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
        .Add(New IO.Ports.SerialPort)
    End With

    If Main.t_startForm.getRCP = 1 Then
        t_RCP1(1).PortName = "COM35"
        t_RCP1(2).PortName = "COM36"
        t_RCP1(3).PortName = "COM37"
        t_RCP1(4).PortName = "COM38"
        t_RCP1(5).PortName = "COM39"
        t_RCP1(6).PortName = "COM40"
        t_RCP1(7).PortName = "COM41"
        t_RCP1(8).PortName = "COM42"
        t_RCP1(9).PortName = "COM43"
        t_RCP1(10).PortName = "COM44"
        t_RCP1(11).PortName = "COM45"
        t_RCP1(12).PortName = "COM46"
        t_RCP1(13).PortName = "COM47"
        t_RCP1(14).PortName = "COM48"
        t_RCP1(15).PortName = "COM49"
        t_RCP1(16).PortName = "COM50"
        t_RCP1(17).PortName = "COM51"
        t_RCP1(18).PortName = "COM52"
        t_RCP1(19).PortName = "COM53"
        t_RCP1(20).PortName = "COM54"
        t_RCP1(21).PortName = "COM55"
        t_RCP1(22).PortName = "COM56"
        t_RCP1(23).PortName = "COM57"
        t_RCP1(24).PortName = "COM58"
    End If

    Return t_RCP1
End Function
#End Region
End Class
```

How can I set each newly created tab page to read which switch and port number to assign the corresponding serial port to open comms with?

Comment: _This is a bad design for what your doing (my opinion), it's begging for issues..._ Why design this way? Your not putting hardly anything in these tabpages, but creating them to hold like 2 controls. Why not handle this in a form if you can?

Comment: Ok, then how should I design it?  I'm trying to make each tab it's own environment for configuring network devices and they need to use different serial ports to do it.  The text boxes on each tab page will be filled w/ the output of the network device im connected to.